# Only the first file of the loop is downloaded

Tags: python, oop, loops, ftp, traceback

I have written a class that downloads one file from an ftp site (ftp://ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/allData/5/MOD11A1/) given parts of the file name when a class instance is called. Later on I wrote a for loop and integrated the class instance inside the for loop so that I download multiple files that fall inside a range of dates. It is a range of dates because the files are named according to the date they are produced. So there are daily files. When you run the code you are asked to input a range of dates. The first file of the range is successfully downloaded, but then when the program stops and prints the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "ftplib04Simplified.py", line 42, in <module>
        FtpDownloader("ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov","/allData/5/MOD11A1/",a).findFile(10,11)
      File "ftplib04Simplified.py", line 32, in findFile
        self.ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filename, open(filename,'wb').write)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.3/ftplib.py", line 424, in retrbinary
        with self.transfercmd(cmd, rest) as conn:
      File "/usr/lib/python3.3/ftplib.py", line 386, in transfercmd
        return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
      File "/usr/lib/python3.3/ftplib.py", line 352, in ntransfercmd
        resp = self.sendcmd(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.3/ftplib.py", line 259, in sendcmd
        return self.getresp()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.3/ftplib.py", line 233, in getresp
        raise error_perm(resp)
    ftplib.error_perm: 550 No such file.

    shell returned 1
```

I know the pure class design will put me to shame, but this is the complete code I have written:
P.S. This was written in Python 3. If you run the code, when asked for input, please input a date after 2001.

```
import ftplib
import math
import datetime as dt
import time
class FtpDownloader:
    """Downloads raster tiles given the date, and tile row and column number"""
    def __init__(self,site,directory,raw_date,ftp=None):
        """logs in to ftp"""
        self.site=site
        self.directory=directory
        self.raw_date=raw_date
        self.ftp=ftplib.FTP(site)
        self.ftp.login()
        self.convert_date()
    def convert_date(self):
        """converts YYYY-MM-DD format to year and day of the year"""
        year=self.raw_date.strftime("%Y")
        day=self.raw_date.strftime("%j")
        self.go_to_folder(year,day)
    def go_to_folder(self,year,day):
        """sets the current FTP directory"""
        self.ftp.cwd(self.directory+"%s/%s/" % (year,day))
    def findFile(self,h,v,fileList=[]):
        """checks for the file containing the given h and h and downloads it using retrbinary"""
        hh= "%02d" % h
        vv= "%02d" % v
        tilename = "h%sv%s" % (hh,vv)
        print ("Image tile %s is downloading..." % tilename)
        self.ftp.retrlines('NLST',fileList.append)
        for filename in fileList:
            if tilename in filename:
                self.ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filename, open(filename,'wb').write)
                print ("File downloaded")
                break
        else:
            print (filename, "not found")
        self.ftp.close()
start=dt.datetime.strptime(input("Enter a start date in YYYY-MM-DD format "),"%Y-%m-%d")
end=dt.datetime.strptime(input("Enter an end date in YYYY-MM-DD format "),"%Y-%m-%d")
for i in range((end-start).days + 1):
    a=(start+dt.timedelta(days=i)).date()
    FtpDownloader("ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov","/allData/5/MOD11A1/",a).findFile(10,11)
```

Answer (score -1):

That is just what you instructed the computer to do: `break`breaks out of the downloading loop as soon as you download the first file:

```
def findFile(self,h,v,fileList=[]):
    """checks for the file containing the given h and h and downloads it using retrbinary"""
    hh= "%02d" % h
    vv= "%02d" % v
    tilename = "h%sv%s" % (hh,vv)
    print ("Image tile %s is downloading..." % tilename)
    self.ftp.retrlines('NLST',fileList.append)
    for filename in fileList:
        if tilename in filename:
            self.ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filename, open(filename,'wb').write)
            print ("File downloaded")
            break
    else:
        print (filename, "not found")
    self.ftp.close()
```

Just replace the `break` for `continue` above and it should work. - Better yet, since tehre are no other statements in your for loop, just remove that line entirely.

Comment: I tried with ´continue´ but it does not work. 'break' is inside the class. I have used it to break the operation if the file with the required name is found. But then, another class instance is initiated from the beginning by the loop at the bottom of the code I posted. So, that 'break' is inside the class. The loop we're talking about is outside the class and iterates over class instances.